# why does my app.get not return a response?

Tags: node.js, express

On node js, I'm trying to do a post request, before that though I want to test if a get request can give me a response.

On my browser, I have the following URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/home/finishpage/client/index.html
```

Now when I set up a get request, nothing comes back, e.g.

```
app.get("/home/finishpage/client/index.html", (req,res)=>{
  console.log("testing get request")
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"/index.html")) //dont mind this
})
```

The console.log doesn't print in this instance, which means I'm not getting the res I want.

Now if I add a fake rout like this:

```
app.get("/home/finishpage/client/index.html/fake", (req,res)=>{
  console.log("testing")
  res.sendFile("test")
})
```

and go to my browser and search:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/home/finishpage/client/index.html/fake
```

This give me a response, and excutes the console.log("testing") command.

What am I not understanding.

Comment: _"which means I'm not getting the res I want"_. So what _are_ you getting as a response? There's nothing inherently wrong with your handler (the one ending on `index.html`) so there's some piece of context missing from your question.

Comment: When you put `http://127.0.0.1:3000/home/finishpage/client/index.html` into the browser, what happens?  What displays?  What does the console in the browser show?   Are you getting an error? This is a basic piece of debugging info that you have not included.

Comment: Do you have an `express.static()` route that would somehow handle the path `/home/finishpage/client`?  If so, it may be serving `index.html` from that directory.

Answer (score -1):

you need to serve static files for express app

```
app.use(express.static({folderPath}));
```

Comment: How does this answer the question being asked?